# problema ao arrastar imagem ckeditor

Tags: javascript, imagem, upload, ckeditor

Estou começando a usar o plugin ckeditor, consigo normalmente mandar uma imagem pro editor, só que quando arrasto a imagem pra outro lugar, ela desaparece, e da o aviso dessa segunda imagem aqui, quando copio e colo uma imagem no editor, da o mesmo problema. Alguém já teve este problema?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu arquivo **config.js** está assim:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
    config.uploadUrl = '/img';
    config.inlinesave = {
        postUrl: '../data'
    };
    config.mathJaxLib = '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
};
```

**Alguém sabe o que pode ser?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, eu utilizo a versão do CKEditor 4, não tive este problema desde que comecei a utilizar este código abaixo:

no meu script utilizo esta chamada para informar o textarea:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'texto1', {
            customConfig: 'config.js'
            ,on: {
                instanceReady: function( ev ) {
                    // Output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>.
                    abreCarregando();
                    this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p', {
                        indent: true,
                        breakBeforeOpen: true,
                        breakAfterOpen: false,
                        breakBeforeClose: false,
                        breakAfterClose: true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

No config tenho estas informações para também melhorar na interpretação:

```
 config.allowedContent = true;
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

Desta forma sempre movi as imagens de uma posição para outra sem problemas, tente utilizar

Comment: o que tem nessa função "abreCarregando()"?

Comment: é uma função que coloquei para abrir uma imagem estilo do ajax loading... até ele terminar de carregar o editor no textarea

Comment: nossa, me passa o script dela por favor :)

Comment: segue [https://jsfiddle.net/marsites/54bj0sh1/]

Comment: O link não ta acessível aqui pra mim :(

Comment: Ah, consegui, o colchetes ficou junto com o link, daí ficou invalido

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/marsites/54bj0sh1/